# How can I call GetRawInputDeviceInfo using JNA?

Tags: java, jna, user32

I want to call [GetRawInputDeviceInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645597(v=vs.85).aspx) from my Java application using [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna).

This is what my JNA `Library` interface looks like:

```
public static final UINT RIDI_DEVICEINFO = new UINT(0x2000000b);

public static DWORD RIM_TYPE_KEYBOARD = new DWORD(1);

public static class RID_DEVICE_INFO extends Structure {
  public DWORD cbSize;
  public DWORD dwType;
  public RID_DEVICE_INFO_ ridDeviceInfo_;

  @Override
  protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {
    return asList("cbSize", "dwType", "ridDeviceInfo_");
  }
}

public static class RID_DEVICE_INFO_ extends Structure {
  public RID_DEVICE_INFO_MOUSE mouse;
  public RID_DEVICE_INFO_KEYBOARD keyboard;
  public RID_DEVICE_INFO_HID hid;

  @Override
  protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {
    return asList("mouse", "keyboard", "hid");
  }
}

public static class RID_DEVICE_INFO_MOUSE extends Structure {
  public DWORD dwId;
  public DWORD dwNumberOfButtons;
  public DWORD dwSampleRate;
  public BOOL fHasHorizontalWheel;

  @Override
  protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {
    return asList("dwId", "dwNumberOfButtons", "dwSampleRate", "fHasHorizontalWheel");
  }
}

public static class RID_DEVICE_INFO_KEYBOARD extends Structure {
  public DWORD dwType;
  public DWORD dwSubType;
  public DWORD dwKeyboardMode;
  public DWORD dwNumberOfFunctionKeys;
  public DWORD dwNumberOfIndicators;
  public DWORD dwNumberOfKeysTotal;

  @Override
  protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {
    return asList("dwType", "dwSubType", "dwKeyboardMode", "dwNumberOfFunctionKeys", "dwNumberOfIndicators", "dwNumberOfKeysTotal");
  }
}

public static class RID_DEVICE_INFO_HID extends Structure {
  public DWORD dwVendorId;
  public DWORD dwProductId;
  public DWORD dwVersionNumber;
  public USHORT usUsagePage;
  public USHORT usUsage;

  @Override
  protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {
    return asList("dwVendorId", "dwProductId", "dwVersionNumber", "usUsagePage", "usUsage");
  }
}

public UINT GetRawInputDeviceInfo(HANDLE hDevice, UINT uiCommand, PointerByReference pData, IntByReference pcbSize);
```

Then, I use `GetRawInputDeviceInfo` like this:  (Assume `hDevice` is a valid `HANDLE` obtained from somewhere.)

```
UINT uiCommand = RIDI_DEVICEINFO;
RID_DEVICE_INFO deviceInfo = new RID_DEVICE_INFO();
deviceInfo.cbSize.setValue(deviceInfo.size());
PointerByReference pData = new PointerByReference(deviceInfo.getPointer());
IntByReference pcbSize = new IntByReference(deviceInfo.size());
UINT lResult = INSTANCE.GetRawInputDeviceInfo(hDevice, uiCommand, pData, pcbSize);
```

My problem is that lResult is -1 which GetRawInputDeviceInfo's documentation says indicates that `pData` was not large enough for the device info.  Did I define `pData` or `cbSize` incorrectly?  If so, what is the correct way to define them in this case?

My JNA version is 4.1.0.  My application is running on Java 8 on Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: I think your inner `RID_DEVICE_INFO_` should be a `Union`.  It's also a bit easier to use `int` rather than `DWORD`, especially for `cbSize`.

Comment: Compare the size returned by your call with that returned by `Structure.size()` and the value of `sizeof(RID_DEVICE_INFO)`.

Answer (score 1):

At the very least you need to modify your structure to have the proper representation.  You currently have three individual fields where instead you should have a `Union`.  That will make your structure's size larger than intended.

In addition, you should pass the structure directly as the third argument (using `PointerByReference` is not only incorrect, but the native code will receive the address of a pointer rather than the address of your structure).  When passing the structure directly, JNA knows when it needs to sync the Java fields with native memory.

```
public interface DeviceAccess extends StdCallLibrary {
    public static class RID_DEVICE_INFO extends Structure {
        public int cbSize;
        public int dwType;
        public RID_DEVICE_INFO_ ridDeviceInfo_;

        // Ensure the active field corresponds to what is read back from native memory
        protected void read() {
            super.read();
            type = RID_DEVICE_INFO_HID.class;
            switch(dwType) {
            case RID_DEVICE_INFO_MOUSE:
                type = RID_DEVICE_INFO_MOUSE.class; break;
            case RID_DEVICE_INFO_KEYBOARD:
                type = RID_DEVICE_INFO_KEYBOARD.class; break;
            default:
                break;
            }
            ridDeviceInfo_.setType(type);
        }

        @Override
        protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {
            return asList("cbSize", "dwType", "ridDeviceInfo_");
        }
    }

    public static class RID_DEVICE_INFO_ extends Union {
        public RID_DEVICE_INFO_MOUSE mouse;
        public RID_DEVICE_INFO_KEYBOARD keyboard;
        public RID_DEVICE_INFO_HID hid;
    }

    public UINT GetRawInputDeviceInfo(HANDLE hDevice, UINT uiCommand, RID_DEVICE_INFO pData, IntByReference pcbSize);
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
UINT uiCommand = RIDI_DEVICEINFO;
RID_DEVICE_INFO deviceInfo = new RID_DEVICE_INFO();
// Could also just put this in the constructor
deviceInfo.cbSize = deviceInfo.size();

IntByReference pcbSize = new IntByReference(deviceInfo.size());
UINT lResult = INSTANCE.GetRawInputDeviceInfo(hDevice, uiCommand, deviceInfo, pcbSize);
```